# Evaluate all conditions sql

Tags: sql

Looking forward to your support.  to explain what i wanted to achieve, i just put sample data and expected output. if you see the attached image,

Input column : c1, c2, c3

output columns to be derived based on the value present in the combination of c1 , c2 and c3. if you see the derived field, we mark "Y' respective to flag column pertains to value present in the field.

[image: Sample data]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CASE` expressions in which you check all three `c1`, `c2` and `c3` for being `NULL` or not.

```
SELECT c1,
       c2,
       c3,
       CASE
         WHEN c1 IS NOT NULL
              AND c2 IS NULL
              AND c3 IS NULL THEN
           'Y'
         ELSE
           'N'
       END c1_flag,
       CASE
         WHEN c1 IS NULL
              AND c2 IS NOT NULL
              AND c3 IS NULL THEN
           'Y'
         ELSE
           'N'
       END c2_flag,
       ...
       CASE
         WHEN c1 IS NOT NULL
              AND c2 IS NOT NULL
              AND c3 IS NOT NULL THEN
           'Y'
         ELSE
           'N'
       END c1_c2_c3_flag
       FROM elbat;
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use a `case` expression:

```
select c1, c2, c3,
       (case when c1 is not null then 'Y' else 'N' end) as c1_flag,
       . . .,
       (case when c1 is not null and c2 is not null then 'Y' else 'N' end) as c12_flag
from t;
```

I'll let you fill in the logic for the remaining flags.

Comment: Thank you Gordon for immediate response. The issue is with case statement is that if first condition is true it skips the evaluation.. for ex, if c1 and c3 has value, flag should yes only to c1_c3='Y' and not for c1='Y' , c3='Y' which is not expected.